# How to replace iframe with AJAX in ColdFusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe, coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion code, and in my code, my code is built inside a table using ColdFusion, where I am setting a variable and creating a query, and then I am passing that variable in an iframe and I am opening my other page called question.cfm in my questionbuilder.cfm page through iframe. How can I replace my code and do this using AJAX, as I have to remove the iframe and use AJAX and Bootstrap?

```
<div class="greyborder mediumtext" style="height:expression(document.body.clientHeight-document.getElementById('topBar').scrollHeight-40)" id="divPaths">
  <cfset builderURL="#request.DomainProtocol##request.DomainURL##ChangeManagerHome#question.cfm?processid=#processid#&category=#category#" />
  <cfif isDefined("URL.pView")>
    <cfset builderURL = builderURL & "&pView=#URL.pView#" />
  </cfif>
  <cfif isDefined("mode") and (mode eq "Add" or mode eq "Edit")>
    <cfset builderURL = builderURL & "&mode=#mode#" />
  </cfif>
  <cfif isDefined("maxrows") and IsNumeric(maxrows) and maxrows gt 0>
    <cfset builderURL = builderURL & "&maxrows=#maxrows#" />
  </cfif>
  <cfif isDefined("pathID") and IsNumeric(pathID) and pathID gt 0>
    <cfset builderURL = builderURL & "&pathID=#pathID#" />
  </cfif>
  <cfif isDefined("qnID") and IsNumeric(qnID)>
    <cfset builderURL = builderURL & "&qnID=#qnID#" />
  </cfif>
  <cfif isDefined("pqn") and IsNumeric(pqn)>
    <cfset builderURL = builderURL & "&pqn=#pqn#" />
  </cfif>
  <cfif isDefined("topt") and IsNumeric(topt)>
    <cfset builderURL = builderURL & "&topt=#topt#" />
  </cfif>
  <cfoutput>
    <iframe src="#builderURL#" name="ifrShowQuestionBuilder" id="ifrShowBuilder" width="100%" frameborder=0 height="100%"></iframe>
  </cfoutput>
</div>
```

Comment: Write a cfc that has all the code that would have run in your iframe.  Use ajax to call the appropriate methods of that cfc and javascript to make any necessary changes to the page content.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like this. 
Create a new cfm file with the following code, make sure it's in the same folder of your question.cfm file, and test it.

```
<cfset builderURL="question.cfm?processid=1&category=2&etc=3..." />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#manual_trigger').click(function(){
        $('#divPaths').load("<cfoutput>#builderURL#</cfoutput>");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="manual_trigger">load</button> <br><br>
  <div id="divPaths"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```